# Phone keypad hides part of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I've got an issue with the keyboard overlapping my layout. When Android brings up the keyboard, it overlaps some of my layout and hides them.

Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Example images:

[image]
[image]

Here is my xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:text="@string/email_provider_text" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioEmailProvider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioYahoo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/radio_selection_yahoo" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioGmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:text="@string/radio_selection_gmail" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:text="@string/txt_to_email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtToAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/to_email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="14dip" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:text="@string/txt_subject_email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSubject"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkAttachment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtBodyPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkAttachment"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="14dip" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_send_email" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_cancle_email" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can set soft input mode properties for activity in manifest, select application tab in manifest, select your activity, set property softInputMode to adjustPan|adjustResize.

or set directly in manifest.xml by inserting following line between tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: i need to add this in activity tag or application tag

Comment: I can't find soft input mode in any of the tag

Comment: I have edited my question, and added some code with it, and I also tried thing what you have said to me but it is not working plz help me with this am i doing something wrong?